# abstract factory and singleton pattern together

Tags: singleton, abstract-factory

Is it possible combine the Abstract factory pattern and singleton pattern together?if yes then,how?give me some example with diagram .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between singleton and factory pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094211/difference-between-singleton-and-factory-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

The abstract factory pattern is all about creating objects. The singleton pattern is all about not creating more than one object of a particular type. How and why do you envisage them working together?