# Design inquiry: Choosing between Singleton, Factory, etc

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton, factory

I have read the book *First Java: Design Patterns* and am a newbie.

I'm making my own game engine just for practice and I'm using Singleton Pattern (I know that's a sin for most of you) to create unique classes like: InputManager, ScreenManager, GameManager, etc. I really find it useful, but I don't want to go against the current.

Is it wiser maybe to use the Factory Method to create this classes (maybe creating them as inner classes) and then pass those objects to whatever class needs them?

Is that bad practice too?

I just want to make sure that there's one instance of those unique classes and only one way to access them.

Maybe something like:

```
public final class Factory(){
private static final InputListener inputlst = new InputListener();  
private static final Screen window = new Screen();
private static final GameManager gameManager = new GameManager();
public Factory(){
}
public static InputListener getInputListener(){
    return inputlst;
}
public static Screen getWindow(){
    return window;
}
private static class InputListener implements KeyListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, MouseWheelListener{      
}
private static class Screen extends JFrame{
}
private static class GameManager{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly patterns are there for a reason. The reason is simple. What change do you expect in your code in future. There is nothing like a `good practice to use patterns`. You use where do you expect the change, based on where you expect the change, you need to take the part that changes OUT and SEPARATE from the part that remains constant. When you do this patterns help you understand.

No SINGLETON is not evil. Its usage is evil. Singleton is a WONDERFUL pattern used to solve a very unique problem with OOP's and OOAD.

Factory cannot be used in place of SINGLETON. Both have very unique propositions. Who knows, if you take time to understand your requirements (and future requirements) carefully, you may realize that you need to use a mix of both. You may need just one factory, and may need to make that factory singleton.

`Understand the change, the future change and separate out what changes from what remains constant`

Comment: Yeah. I was trying to implement something like I said above, but it overcomplicated things. Singleton made the most sense.

Comment: No again, "most sense" is not the criteria.The most important word when you choose a pattern is `Future`.Think about it. If a website needs to add hotel booking to its feature,imagine places in code where this will come. From choice, to payment,to refunds. It will touch all parts of the code. Here a factory is important, since not everyone wants a hotel booking, so why "Create" the object "Hotels" for that user.Saving 1 object creation, will save all those objects from getting created by the millions of visitors daily. 1 mil objects saved,since a factory pattern decides what objects to create.

Comment: Dont worry about it, its a tough concept to get, but once you do, you feel like the architect :) Please take time to understand it. Dont give up.

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to make sure that there's one instance of those unique classes and only one way to access them.

Sounds like the singleton pattern to me: static accessor in the class returns the single instance of that class.

Don't try to overcomplicate things up front with inner classes/passing things around unless you find that you absolutely need to.  See [Difference between singleton and factory pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094211/difference-between-singleton-and-factory-pattern) for some further reading that might help you out.

Comment: Thanks! I know that most people hate singleton pattern, so I was trying to find a way around it. I'm designing the engine thinking what would happen if someone would use it and I don't want them to do certain things, so that's why I was trying to find the better way to do this.

Comment: How does it matter what people hate. Think about it. Obj-C developers hate java, does that mean you will stop using it. Use patterns for the `intent` they exist, not because of a cosmetic reason. Please study more. I recommend `Head First Design Patterns for Java`, just the first 3 chapters will surely ensure that you understand the `intent` of patterns. This books answers "why" patterns. All other books explain "how" to use, and expect that the "why" will just be realized later.

Comment: You are absolutely right. That's my though about it (it doesn't matter what people say about singleton or other particular thing). I've read the wrongs of singleton, but I just thought that i'll use it wherever I feel it useful. I was trying here to understand if singleton is the right choice for this scenario or I'm just making a terrible mistake, but the comments here opened my eyes and confirmed what i thought. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have exactly one instance of those unique classes then singleton is the pattern for you with some method like getInstance etc.

Factory pattern is one which creates and returns new objects of different type but invaribale extending from the same subclass. It's a way of abstracting the instantiation of a class.

Comment: Thanks. So, I think I'll be sticking with singleton then. It made the most sense, but since i hear so many bad comments about it's use...